Why is my installed command not showing in 'cargo --list'?
I have two systems, one is a fresh Linux install, the other a mac.
On macOS, when I run cargo --list --verbose I can see all the inbuilt and externally-installed cargo commands:
% cargo --list --verbose
Installed Commands:
    add                  Add dependencies to a Cargo.toml manifest file
    b                    alias: build
    bench                Execute all benchmarks of a local package
    build                Compile a local package and all of its dependencies
    build-bpf            /Users/username/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/cargo-build-bpf
    build-sbf            /Users/username/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/cargo-build-sbf
    ...
 

On the Linux system, however, despite having the same software installed, the external commands are not shown:
% cargo --list --verbose
Installed Commands:
    add                  Add dependencies to a Cargo.toml manifest file
    b                    alias: build
    bench                Execute all benchmarks of a local package
    build                Compile a local package and all of its dependencies
    c                    alias: check
    ...

However I can see the same file exists in the same directory:
# ls -la ~/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin

-rwxr-xr-x 1 username group  6924136 Mar  3 06:33 cargo-build-bpf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 username group 21154624 Mar  3 06:33 cargo-build-sbf

Why is my installed command not showing in 'cargo --list'?
I have checked PATH and ~/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin is in PATH
What can I do to ensure it appears? I have others tools that invoke cargo build-bpf so running the binary outside cargo won't work.

Does running cargo build-bpf work?

On my system, cargo --list --verbose shows e.g. create-tauri-app     /home/user/.cargo/bin/cargo-create-tauri-app. For a listing of commands, I don't think it matters if your command is in PATH, only if cargo knows where to find it. Did you install the command with cargo install?

What Linux distro are you running? On my machine (debian sid, cargo 1.77), the installed binaries end up in ~/.cargo/bin/  and show up correctly in cargo --list.

Are you sure that that ~/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin is indeed on the PATH for the current shell and user that is executing your cargo command? Maybe try running cargo-build-bpf by itself from the shell.
If it is on the PATH, this should not happen according to the cargo docs, and is not reproducable for me.

Ya, in hindsight my comment was not very helpful. Glad you figured it out anyway!

Originally I thought this was a bug in Cargo, but it's actually GitHub actions. I've edited the post below to reflect that.
Cargo does use PATH to determine the location of the commands shown when you run cargo --list:

3rd party subcommands (ie. programs named cargo-foobar placed in $PATH)...

However due to using GitHub actions, where the ~ is not expanded properly, my PATH was incorrect.
Normally (in bash), adding ~/somedir/bin to PATH would result in /home/username/somedir/bin being added to PATH.
In GitHub actions, adding ~/somedir/bin to GITHUB_PATH won't expand the tilde, resulting in ~/somedir/bin being added, which won't work.
To fix: ensure you do not use tilde when adding items to the PATH in  GitHub actions, eg:
Failing:
- name: Install Solana CLI (beta)
  run: |
    sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/beta/install)"
    echo "~/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin" >> $GITHUB_PATH

Working
- name: Install Solana CLI (beta)
  run: |
    sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/beta/install)"
    echo "/home/runner/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin" >> $GITHUB_PATH

